# Send value from one view to another ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs6

I want to send value from one view to another one, I have a code that's work in `ExtJS 6` but not in `ExtJS 4`.

This is from the first one:

```
var test = Ext.create('test.text', {
    delayedRenderTo: container_id,
    id: 'messageBox-' + meta.rowIndex,
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            value: value
        }
    }
});
```

and **we bind it like this:**

```
Ext.define('test.text', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
        overflow: 'scroller',
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        grow: true,
        growMin: 30,
        growMax: 120,
        disabled: true,
        fullscreen: true,
        bind: {
            value: '{value}',
        },
        fieldStyle: 'font-weight:bold;'
    }]
});
```

What is the alternative for `ExtJS 4` ?

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels were introduced in Ext JS 5 which is why it doesn't work in Ext JS 4.

To do it in Ext JS 4, you'd have to find the component (the `textareafield` in this case) and then execute the setter (`setValue` for this example). It's all manual in Ext JS 4.

Getting the component depends on many things but the best way is to use ComponentQuery and depends where the code executing this would be. First, you'd have to get your `test.text` instance and then use `comp.child('textareafield')`. I cannot give you a silver bullet example as it depends on many factors but using component's `down`, `child`, `query`, `up` methods a good start and they all have different purposes.